# JSF richfaces: update (rerender) element + close popup on click a4j:commandButton

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a a4j:commandButton in my popup. On click I want to hide my popup and rerender some component.

```
<a4j:commandButton type="button" styleClass="left" value="#{bean.value}"
                                     actionListener="#{bean.action}"
                                     render="updComponent"
                                     oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()"/>
```

In this case component is rerendered, but popup isn't hiding.

If I use `rerender="updComponent"` instead of `render="updComponent"`, popup is hiding, but element isn't rerendered.

If I use instead of `oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()"` this:

```
<rich:componentControl target="deactivateIp" event="oncomplete" operation="hide"/>
```

popup isn't hiding, component isn't rerendering.

What I'm doing wrong and how to achieve what I want?

Comment: `oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()"` and `render` will work fine when you will render **form or panel** which contains updComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used onbegin instead of oncomplete and it works for me.
If I don't mistake, it's jsf bug: after render oncomplete event isn't firing.

```
<a4j:commandButton type="button" styleClass="left" value="#{bean.value}"
                                     actionListener="#{bean.action}"
                                     render="updComponent"
                                     onbegin="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()"/>
```

Maybe not the best solution, but I haven't found out any other.